# Java, passing and modifying arrays through different methods, array intersection

Tags: java, arrays, loops

I am trying to pass two arrays, which are recorded by the user in the readData(); method, then have both arrays passed into a method (intersectionDuplicates();) which checks for duplicates in both arrays.  It would then add the values *without* duplicates to 2 new arrays.  These arrays are then passed to a method that finds the intersection/common values between both arrays, and pushes THOSE values to another new array.  This new array is then printed in the printArray(); method.  The readData and printArray method both work as intended.  My confusion lies in passing the array/arrays through each method.  Here is what I have so far.

```
static int SizeofX = 0;
static int SizeofY = 0;
static int [] x = new int[100];    
static int [] y = new int[100];
public static void main (String [] args) {
    int SizeofX = readData(x);
    int SizeofY = readData(y);

    intersectionDuplicates(x, SizeofX, y, SizeofY);


public static int[] intersectionDuplicates (int [] a, int numElementsInA, int [] b, int numElementsInB) {
           int temp2 = 0;
            int temp = 0;
            int [] z = new int [100];
            int [] y = new int [100];
            for (int i=0; i<numElementsInA; i++){
               for (int j=i+1; j<numElementsInA; j++){
                  if (a[j]!=a[i]) {
                        z[temp] = a[i];
                        temp++;
                    }
                }
            }
            for (int i=0; i<numElementsInB; i++){
               for (int j=i+1; j<numElementsInB; j++){
                  if (b[j]!=b[i]) {
                        y[temp2] = a[i];
                        temp2++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }//end intersectionDuplicates


  public static int[] intersection (int [] x, int numElementsInX, int [] y, int numElementsInY) {
     int temp = 0;  
     int [] z = new int [100];
     for (int j=0; j<numElementsInX; j++){
        for (int i=0; i<numElementsInY; i++){
           if (x[j]==y[i]) { 
              z[temp] = x[j];
              temp++;
           }
        } 
     }
     printArray(z, temp);
  }//end intersection
```

How do I pass the new arrays in intersectionDuplicates to the next method intersection?

Also sorry for the length of this question!
Thank you for any assistance!

Comment: I am also not using array.length to find the length of the array as it returns the entire initialized size of the array, not just user entries.

Comment: I am also not using sets as my professor has not yet taught us them, and would like us to do this assignment without.

Comment: A homework question with actual effort? My confidence in humanity is... slightly renewed. I assume you have some typos to correct (`main` is not properly ended and you don't return anything in `intersectionDuplicates`). Try invoking `intersection` at the end of `intersectionDuplicates` (removing the return type from his definition) or return an array in `intersectionDuplicates` to pass it later as a parameter for `intersection`.

Comment: You can just call the `intersection` method form the `intersectionDuplicates`

Comment: Why is this question tagged with `jvm`?

Comment: @Digvijay sorry i still barely know what jvm even means...

Comment: @Gamb Yes I tried to briefly mention main.  I was confused as to how to return intersectionDuplicates, gotcha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Java array length can be found out by using `array.length`. So the length arguments of this method

```
public static int[] intersection (int [] x, int numElementsInX, int [] y, int numElementsInY)
```

are superfluous.

I guess your `intersection` method is wrong. When `x[i]` is different from `y[j]` do you need to put that in your `z` array.

Also `intersectionDuplicates` is calculating common elements in `x` and `y` arrays twice. You need to get rid of one of the for loops.

In your main method, you have *handles* of both `x` and `y`. You can pass the same to any method to get the `z` array. You can also give this `z` array to your `printArray` method.

Comment: Doesn't array.length get the initialized size of the array rather then the size of array with actual data input?  My array is initialized to 100 but has data entries under 100.

Comment: @user2210274 Indeed, and the offset between the `length` and `elementsInY` should be all `null` values.

Comment: Ok, here is a kludge. Inititialize `z` in main as `z = new int[100]`. And pass this to your methods. All your methods then return the number of elements in `z`.(yout temp variable, please give it a better name)

Comment: I am curious as to how do you create your arrays before asking for the number of elements. Someday you will get `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`

Comment: I just have a counter going in a while loop that limits user input from array[0 to 99].  Its definitely not foolproof but works for homework. I know everything above is the long way around.

Comment: `z` will be a scratch array where your methods fill in their values.

Answer (score 1):

You can add the following call to intersection before the end of method intersectionDuplicate

```
MyClassName.intersection(z, temp, y, temp2);
```

Comment: Ah.  Duh.  Lol, think I just needed that little push!  But you dont need the myclassname part as it is already part of that class correct?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Make two method 
1. Which returns distinct numbers in array

```
    Array.sort(x)
    int ele=x[0]
    for(int i=0;i<x.length();i++)
     {
           if(ele==x[i])
               continue;
           else{
                  ele=x[i]
                  count++
                }
     }
```

In the end count will give u length of new arrays.Now new arrays of these size in intersection duplicates.

2 Method.Use the almost same logic to find distinct values in new array.
When u have two array suppose let them temp1[],temp2[]. You call intersection method like this

```
              intersection(temp1,temp1.length(),temp2,temp2.lenght())
```

hope this helps.. I did this way , the same thing.
One day will upload this.

Comment: okay.  In your first for loop you say for(int=0..., which variable are you referring to, ele?

Comment: ele is used to refer to ur array first element. since array is sort next element has to be greater than that or equal(duplicates) so leave count in that. In the end you will get array size. this will not give u ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Comment: i also changed the code if and else condition above.. Do check it once..!! If you find worth you can mark it as answer

Comment: array.sort is a java.util right?  Actually my professor is not letting us use a java.util other then Scanner to input information :(

Comment: in that case use bubble sort method to sort your array.
Find it here [link](http://www.programmingsimplified.com/c/source-code/c-program-bubble-sort)

Answer (score 0):

As I suppose you cannot run `intersection` method from `intersectionDuplicates`, so you may use methods like

```
public static int[] intersectionDuplicates (int [] a, int numElementsInA, int [] b, int  numElementsInB, int[] z,int[] y) {
 //do the same as in your code, but without initializing z and y, they must be initialized in main method
 return new int[]{temp,temp2};
}
```

and passing the empty arrays from your main method. They are references, so after running intersectionDuplicates they both will be field and available in your main method.

To get the `temp2` and `temp` variable you may return `int[2]` from your method or again pass the `int[2]` array as parameter.

Answer (score -1):

```
public class ModifyArray{
public static void main(String[] args){


System.out.println("1-REMOVE");
System.out.println("2-ADD");
System.out.println("3-EXIT");
System.out.print("Enter a Menu from 1-3 :  ");
int b =Keyboard.readInt();
int m = 0;
int[] arr = new int [b];
            switch(b){

                case 1: System.out.println("REMOVE:");
                        System.out.print("Input a number:");
                        int a =Keyboard.readInt();
                        for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
                            if(arr[i]==b){
                                System.out.print(b + " is found at index " + i);

                            }else{
                                System.out.print("Numbers not found! ");
                            }

                        }



                        break;

                case 2: System.out.println("ADD");
                        System.out.print("Input a number :");
                        int z =Keyboard.readInt();


                case 3: System.out.print("EXIT");
                        System.exit(0);

                }




            }




        }
```